# Constraint Layout without any children views with height wrap_content takes full parent height

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

> **Que:** Look at the below xml layout file. Here the nested ConstraintLayout
>   with id `clLoginStub` has height set to `wrap_content` but it
>   still takes up the full height of the screen. Why is it happening and how to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f4f0f0">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clLoginStub"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#d50000"
            android:paddingBottom="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
            android:id="@+id/xviewGuideline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/clLoginStub"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvLoginMethods"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#6fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/xviewGuideline"
            tools:itemCount="3"
            tools:listitem="@layout/sign_in_button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I thought it would be an IDE bug but it also happens when running the app.

When I put a child element, the layout works fine. Its when it is empty that the problem occurs. Instead, it should have 0dp height when it is empty. The layout is empty because I want to inflate different views within it at run time based on some conditions.

[Here is a snapshot of the layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJRN1.jpg)

Comment: You have two `ConstraintLayout` tags but only one closing tag, either remove one of them or close the open one.

Comment: @MichaelStoddart look closely, the 2nd one is closed in declaration

Comment: It seems that _ConstraintLayout_ doesn't like to be childless when the height is `wrap_content`. A workaround is to place a zero-height _Space_ view (or one that has visibility set to `gone`) to make this work. This might be work a bug report if you are so inclined.

Comment: why are you using nested ConstraintLayout and please share layout image which you want to achieve?

Comment: @Cheticamp I am using a Space view as a workaround for now... but I was curious about why its happening

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan I have shared the image. Just imagine the red area to be 0dp and not visible (80dp if you consider padding)

Comment: Perhaps it's a defect.

Answer (score 0):

this create 3 layout same height in screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f4f0f0">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clLoginStub"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#d50000"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/xviewGuideline"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/xviewGuideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clLoginStub"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rvLoginMethods"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvLoginMethods"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#6fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/xviewGuideline"
        tools:itemCount="3" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: umm... whaaaaaat..??

Comment: sory for my bad answer,but other way is use androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline and set layout_constraintGuide_percent for your layout

Comment: guidelines and other stuff won't work... my problem is different, besides, it want to know why is it happening :p

Answer (score 0):

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/xviewGuideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/clLoginStub"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clLoginStub"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

In my case, I put "app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf" in  and it's solved.